# bug in java for gregorian calendar

Tags: java

I am trying to add 89 days to `CurrentDate` through `GregorianCalendar` which is returning 31/04/2015.  Below is code snippet.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String dt="31012013";  
now.set(Integer.parseInt(dt.substring(4)),Integer.parseInt(dt.substring(2,4)),Integer.parseInt(dt.substring(0,2))); 
now.add(Calendar.DATE, 89); 
String matdate=Integer.toString(now.get(Calendar.DATE))+ "/"+ (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) ) +"/" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

After executing this code, `matdate` value is coming as **31/04/2013**

Comment: You might want to look into JodaTime for these operations, it simplifies things like adding dates.

Comment: sorry it's confusing : you said the result is 31/04/2015 at the beginning of your post and 31/04/2013 at the end. please clarify the result you have and the result you are expecting.

Comment: Normally, compilers have very, very rare bugs, even more so when they have been in production and mass use since many years and lots of versions.

Comment: Calendar class month starts with 0 not 1

Answer (score 5):

This is because `java.util.Calendar` months start with **0 not 1**, that is, 4 is May. Besides the best way to format dates is `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

```
    String matdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(now.getTime()));
```

Or better use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for calendar and time related codes.